# setenv() in c doesn't add a my custom bin directory

Tags: c, unix, path, setenv

I would like to add my folmer **/myBin/bin** which have executable inside to the PATH environment variable so i can **execvp()** these.

The **setenv()** doesn't seems to add my directory to the PATH, what am I missing ?

Thank you

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void){
    char binDir[PATH_MAX+1];
    strcpy(binDir,"~/myBin/bin");
    char pathDir[PATH_MAX+1];
    strcpy(pathDir,"PATH");

    printf("Variable d'environnement (%s)\n\n\n", getenv("PATH"));
    setenv(pathDir,binDir,0);
    printf("Variable d'environnement (%s)\n", getenv("PATH"));
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have set last argument of setenv to 0, as per setenv documentation
"if overwrite is zero, then the value of name is not changed. ", you may try passing 1 as overwrite arguent to setenv

Comment: With 1 as a parameter, it remove all other variables in the PATH, then add my folder. How can I just add the folder to the end of the PATH, without removing existing variables there? @Pras

Comment: You can getenv first, extract existing path, then append your new path to it and  then set that path using setenv